# Plugin to control NURBS to mesh curve divisions

Tags: rhino3d, opennurbs

I've written a few plugins using C# and I'm familiar with Python, however I find the documentation in the SDK very difficult to understand.  My previous plugins that I've written are largely based on modifications to collections of sample code.

Using Rhino3d, I'd like more control over how it meshes curves.  I'd like to control the number of mesh vertex divisions on a curve/arc using my algorithm based on the angle and radius of the curve.  I actually already have a plugin that calculates the number of divisions (range) to use.

Currently I am forced to export it into ANSYS APDL (where I can directly specify divisions by selecting each line), meshing, then importing back to rhino.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info on what kind of geometry you are trying to mesh? Which commands in Rhino have you tried so far? In my experience the surface mesh density broadly reflects the number of control points in the bounding curve.

Comment: Did you try asking on http://discourse.mcneel.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

in fact mesh is a graph and Ansys can handle graphs, but Ansys SDK is tricky... as a beginner check this posts:
http://sysmagazine.com/posts/140397/
alyms-alis.blogspot.ch/2013/01/integration-c-and-module-of-ansys.html

meshing is a science itself. There are some algorithms and approaches which are working fine and found implementation as http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/ag-geom/publications/db/KNP07-QuadCover.pdf

Comment: please provide a full answer to the question, not just a link